# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.view.View android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.itemView'

Tags: android

I'm using Android RecyclerView with multiple ViewHolders.
When i set the adapter the i'm getting below error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.view.View android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.itemView' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6686)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5869)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2232)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1559)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1519)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:614)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3225)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
                                                                                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
                                                                                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
                                                                                  at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1308)
                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                                                  at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:350)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
                                                                                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
                                                                                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:724)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2422)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1504)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1761)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1392)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6752)
03-04 19:08:44.817 3862-3862/com.bocawestcc.cobaltmemberapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
                                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
                                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
                                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
```

Here is Adapter Class:

```
public class EventModifyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    final int VIEW_TYPE_MEMBER = 0;
    final int VIEW_TYPE_GUEST = 1;
    final int VIEW_TYPE_BUDDY = 2;

    private final static int TYPE_CALL=1,TYPE_SMS=2;
    private List<Object> modifyListData =new ArrayList();
    // Context is not used here but may be required to
    // perform complex operations or call methods from outside
    private Context context;

    // Constructor
    public EventModifyAdapter(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }

    public void setEventModifyData(List<Object> modifyListData){
        this.modifyListData = modifyListData;
    }

    // We need to override this as we need to differentiate
    // which type viewHolder to be attached
    // This is being called from onBindViewHolder() method
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (modifyListData.get(position) instanceof MemberList) {
            return VIEW_TYPE_MEMBER;
        } else if (modifyListData.get(position) instanceof GuestList) {
            return VIEW_TYPE_GUEST;
        } else if (modifyListData.get(position) instanceof BuddyList) {
            return VIEW_TYPE_BUDDY;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    // Invoked by layout manager to replace the contents of the views
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        int viewType=holder.getItemViewType();
        switch (viewType){
            case VIEW_TYPE_MEMBER:
                MemberList memberListList=(MemberList) modifyListData.get(position);
                ((MemberViewHolder)holder).showMemberDetails(memberListList);
                break;
            case VIEW_TYPE_GUEST:
                GuestList guestListList=(GuestList) modifyListData.get(position);
                ((GuestViewHolder)holder).showGuestDetails(guestListList);
                break;
            case VIEW_TYPE_BUDDY:
                BuddyList buddyList=(BuddyList) modifyListData.get(position);
                ((BuddyViewHolder)holder).showBuddyDetails(buddyList);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){return modifyListData.size();}

    // Invoked by layout manager to create new views
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // Attach layout for single cell
        int layout = 0;
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
        // Identify viewType returned by getItemViewType(...)
        // and return ViewHolder Accordingly
        switch (viewType){
            case VIEW_TYPE_MEMBER:
                layout = R.layout.row_all_members;
                View membersView = LayoutInflater
                        .from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(layout, parent, false);
                viewHolder=new MemberViewHolder(membersView);
                break;
            case VIEW_TYPE_GUEST:
                layout = R.layout.row_all_guests;
                View guestsView = LayoutInflater
                        .from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(layout, parent, false);
                viewHolder=new GuestViewHolder(guestsView);
                break;
            case VIEW_TYPE_BUDDY:
                layout = R.layout.row_all_members;
                View buddyView = LayoutInflater
                        .from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(layout, parent, false);
                viewHolder=new BuddyViewHolder(buddyView);
                break;
            default:
                viewHolder=null;
                break;
        }
        return viewHolder;
    }

    // First ViewHolder of object type Call
    // Reference to the views for each call items to display desired information
    public class MemberViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView tv_member_name,tv_member_id;
        private ImageView iv_close;

        public MemberViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            // Initiate view
            tv_member_name=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_member_name);
            tv_member_id=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_member_id);
            iv_close=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_close);
        }

        public void showMemberDetails(MemberList mem){
            // Attach values for each item
            String memName   = mem.getMemberName();
            String memid   = mem.getMemberID();
            tv_member_name.setText(memName);
            tv_member_id.setText(memid);

            iv_close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    try {
                        modifyListData.remove(position);
                        notifyItemRemoved(position);
                    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // Second ViewHolder of object type SMS
    // Reference to the views for each call items to display desired information
    public class GuestViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView tv_guest_name,tv_guestType;
        private ImageView iv_close;

        public GuestViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            // Initiate view
            tv_guest_name =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_guest_name);
            tv_guestType =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_guestType);
            iv_close=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_close);
        }

        public void showGuestDetails(GuestList guest){
            // Attach values for each item
            String guestName   = guest.getGuestName();
            tv_guest_name.setText(guestName);
        }
    }

    // Second ViewHolder of object type SMS
    // Reference to the views for each call items to display desired information
    public class BuddyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView tv_member_name,tv_member_id;
        private ImageView iv_close;

        public BuddyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            // Initiate view
            tv_member_name =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_member_name);
            tv_member_id=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_member_id);
            iv_close=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_close);
        }

        public void showBuddyDetails(BuddyList buddy){
            // Attach values for each item
            String buddyName   = buddy.getMemberName();
            String memid   = buddy.getMemberID();
            tv_member_name.setText(buddyName);
            tv_member_id.setText(memid);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is Adapter Calling or setting code from activity :

```
  linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerviewModify.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        eventModifyAdapter =new EventModifyAdapter(EventRegistrationActivity.this);
        recyclerviewModify.setAdapter(eventModifyAdapter);

        eventModifyAdapter.setEventModifyData(finalModifyList);
        eventModifyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Please help me out from this error because in logcat there is no any clue of where the actual error is getting from .
All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: don't post -1 for viewType and don't set viewHolder=null in onCreateViewHolder

Comment: then what i will pass with return?

Comment: When you change the data set you should notify your adapter. `setEventModifyData` have to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` or if you want to change data later again i would suggest to use a `DiffUtils`. Also the first list you can init in your `constructor`

Comment: Can you please see my updated code .. ialso calling the notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: @LaxmanLucky return some real view and viewType (one of three)

Comment: About viewTypes. Make your last `else if` just `else`. Then you wont need to return `-1`. Same logic in `onCreateViewHolder`... use `default case` for your last `ViewHolder`. Try to use `enum` instead of local fields.

Comment: no effects... still getting crashed

Answer (score 3):

I got this issue,  Because I call methods onCreateViewHolder and return null, Causes the holder variable in the createviewholder method in the Recycleview class to be null. So make the return value of method oncreateviewholder not null.

Answer (score 0):

I had come across this same issue. I had used three viewholders to hold three types of elements.
Turns out there was an issue in getItemViewType(int position).

Just make sure the integer returned by this method is ALWAYS one of the view types that you have defined.

Like make sure the default: value set inside the switch case, if u have used it, is NEVER USED.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this and it'll work fine:

```
  default:
           viewHolder=null;
           break;
```

This may happen if your `onCreateViewHolder` method returns `null`.